# ¿Es posible acceder a una propiedad de una clase base usando Generics en Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Tengo la siguiente clase que será la base para las entidades de la aplicación

```
namespace Base {
    export abstract class BaseEntity {
        endpoint: string;
        public abstract getId(): string;
    }
}
```

y la implementación de esta clase está dada de esta forma:

```
namespace Example {
    export class Account extends Base.BaseEntity {
        accountId?: string;
        name?: string;
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.endpoint = "accounts";
        }

        public getId(): string {
            return this.accountId;
        }
    }
}
```

el objetivo de esto e poder obtener el valor de la propiedad `endpoint` de cada clase para conocer la url del método web definido en una Web Api.

Aquí el ejemplo:

```
namespace Base {
    export class BaseService<T extends BaseEntity> {
        private url: string;
        constructor(
            private $q: angular.IQService,
            private $http: angular.IHttpService) {
            this.url = `http://localhost:81/api/${(<BaseEntity>T).endpoint}`; //ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
        }
    }
}
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error sobre esta instrucción  `${(<BaseEntity>T).endpoint}`:

> //ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que endpoint es un miembro de la clase `BaseEntity` y por otro lado T es un tipo, no se puede aplicar type assertion `<BaseEntity>` a un tipo sino a una variable.

La solución solo para que compile consiste en almacenar una instancia del tipo T en el momento que se contruye una instancia de `BaseService` al cual se le puede llamar a su propiedad `endpoint`

```
namespace Base {
    export class BaseService<T extends BaseEntity> {
        private url: string;
        constructor(
            private $q: angular.IQService,
            private $http: angular.IHttpService,
            private entity: T) {
            this.url = `http://localhost:81/api/${entity.endpoint}`;
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo una mejor solución sería quitar la propiedad endpoint de la clase BaseEntity ya que no le pertenece realmente a la entidad sino ubicarla en su lugar en BaseService de modo que cada Service que lo herede pueda setear su propio endpoint.

```
namespace Base {
    export abstract class BaseEntity {
        public abstract getId(): string;
    }
}

namespace Example {
    export class Account extends Base.BaseEntity {
        accountId?: string;
        name?: string;
        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        public getId(): string {
            return this.accountId;
        }
    }
}

namespace Base {
    export class BaseService<T extends BaseEntity> {
        private url: string;
        constructor(
            private $q: angular.IQService,
            private $http: angular.IHttpService,
            private endpoint: string) {
            this.url = `http://localhost:81/api/${this.endpoint}`;
        }
    }
}

namespace Example {
    export class AccountService extends Base.BaseService<Account>
    {
        constructor(
            $q: angular.IQService,
            $http: angular.IHttpService,
            endpoint: string) {
            super($q, $http, 'accounts');
        }
    }
}
```